# How to pass a fieldtext value from view another view swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui-list, swiftui-form, swiftui

I put the fieldtext in view called fieldtextmydesine and also put the button in view named login and I called fieldtextmydesin view and login view in contentview how do I print the field text value when I press the login button

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use NavigationView and NavigationLink instead of a button.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var name: String = "Tim"

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
        Text("Hello, \(name)!")
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(name: self.$name)){
        Text("LogIn")
       }
    }
  }
}
```

//Second ContenView

```
struct SecondView: View {
 @Binding var name: String
  var  body: some View {
   Text("Hello \(text)")
  }
 }
```

From what I understand from your question, you are trying to pass a value entered into a Text-Field from one View to another. If this is what your asking then this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet can help you:
You can bind property to textfield like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name: String = "Tim"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            Text("Hello, \(name)!")
        }
    }
}
```

You can add button and print `name` on button tap line you need. You can pass name property to another text on tap. Or hide text view and show on tap and another ways

Answer (score 0):

You can display print name either on the console or can display name in an alert. In the below snippet, to fetch name entered in text field on button click requires state variable instead of normal variable. It is created with @State keyword. State parameter manages the state in the View. So whenever there is change in state all the components that are associated with the state will be rendered again.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginUI: View {
    @State var textName: String = ""
    @State var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 2.0) {
            TextField("Enter your name", text: $textName).padding(10)

              Button(action: {
                print("Entered name is \(self.textName)")
                self.showAlert = true

              }, label: {Text("Login")}).padding().background(Color.gray)
        }
        .padding(5.0)
        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Entered name is"), message: Text("\(self.textName)"))
    }
    }
}

struct LoginUI_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginUI()
    }
}
```